# angularjs watching radio button for change working only at first selections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a list of radio buttons and I am trying to watch the change of selection with $watch in a directive. I am only able to trigger the watch at the first selection of those elements.

My html:

```
<p ng-repeat="(key,item) in option" style="margin-bottom:0px ">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" is-valid ng-model="value" selected-key="value" name="select" value="{{key}}" ng-checked="getChecked($index)"> {{item.name}}
    </label>
</p>
```

My Directive returns:

```
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        selectedKey: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('selectedKey', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
            alert('triggered')
        });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried watching with "value" only but watch doesnot get triggered.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can simply use `ngChange`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange Why do you need custom directive?

Comment: ya I can do that but then I would have to add another controller function, I already have a directive attribute called is-valid used for similar task. I think It would be better to write less I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that `ngRepeat` creates a new scope for every iteration item. It means that the `value` is individual for every radio button. As the result watch expression is triggered only once per radio input, it never changes after that.

What you need to do is to use parent scope model holding selected radio value. You can achieve this by declaring model in your controller, e.g.:

```
$scope.radio = {value: null};
```

and use this model for every radio button. In addition I dropped redundant `selected-key` attribute, you don't need it since you already have ng-model one pointing to the same `radio.value`.

All together the directive will look like:

```
app.directive('isValid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            selectedKey: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('selectedKey', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                console.log('triggered')
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/K8HJo8c81dFRKxZ2oyus?p=preview

Comment: so my html would be
`<input type="radio" is-valid ng-model="radio.value" name="select" value="{{key}}" ng-checked="getChecked($index)"> {{item.name}}`
right?
It is still triggered only once per radio button.